# Downloading multiple csv files from Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-datastore, export-to-csv

So I found a lot of good info on here from how to download data from GAE to a csv.. where I'm stuck is how to export multiple csv files

Summary:
I have a webapp that takes multiple inputs and for each input, it sends data to the datastore and then writes from the datastore to the csv. Sample code is below:

```
class RunScript(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self): 
    listOfTickers = self.request.get('Stocks').split(", ")
    for i in listOfTickers:
        self.main(cgi.escape(i))
```

main method calls other functions to get the data and ends up writing to csv via the code below:

```
item_query=Item.query().order(Item.keyOfItem).fetch()
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(self.response.out)
    for a in item_query:
        rowToWrite=a.row+a.value
        writer.writerow(rowToWrite)
        #empty datastore as data is drawn out
        a.key.delete()
```

at this point, the sub function ends and we go back to the for loop in the post() function. I thought the sub function ending would trigger GAE to download the first csv and then download the second csv after it goes through the code again. However, what happens is I get one csv at the end with both sets of data in it.

Any thoughts as to why this is happening? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep writing data to the same response, i.e. to the same file. A response cannot return multiple files.

You should create several files, archive them together into a single file, and then return this archive.

Comment: hmm.. I'm still learning the nuances of GAE so please excuse me if this is basic but can you explain that a little bit more? I assume you mean something like create multiple .csvs and then zip them up and download that one zip file; how would I do that?

or is there a different way to call multiple responses?

Comment: Each request has only one response. There are no ways to have multiple responses without multiple requests. This is not specific to GAE. And yes, you need to create a zip  from several csv files. This should be a separate question - or there may be one already asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

To create a response that has multiple separate pieces of data in it, you should look into [`multipart` content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request). This is usually used in request to send multipart form data, but it can also be used in response.

There is some support in browsers for multipart response: [Browser support of multipart responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806228/browser-support-of-multipart-responses)

There is also a [mpAjax](https://github.com/getify/mpAjax) javascript library that can help you parse the multipart response. You might want to [test it](http://test.getify.com/mpAjax/).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative yo can also write the cvs's to a single zip archive.

Or you can write you csv files to  cloudstorage and use cloudstorage to download the files if you need them.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133) for using cloudstorage. It contains an example to create a zip archive.