# How can I build HttpResponse with multipart ContentType

Tags: python, django, web, httpresponse

I have purpose to send in single response several data types: plain/text (or json) and image as bytes. And I see, how I can [set contenttype](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) for my response. So and I can set some multipart type:

```
response = HttpResponse(my_data, content_type='multipart/alternative')
```

But how I understand, this way leads to difficulties: I need set also content type header for each part of the response. But I cann't find in docs, how can I do that. And is it possible for django?

Thanks for your ideas

Comment: PS: I saw answers about encode of the image-bytes to base64 and passing it as text/plain to browser, but I seems this way is very costly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This content type is for mail purposes. It will not be rendered correctly by web browsers. 
Check this question: [Browser support of multipart responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806228/browser-support-of-multipart-responses)

Comment: Thanks, I saw that. But I come to conclusion that the answer is old and might lose relevance (from 2009-2014 years dates of answers there for now 2019). And I think actual browsers - may be - now can understand the types. Am I wrong?

Comment: I see their tests from 2019. So everything the same. No point to implement it.