# WADO-RS: URL to video bulkdata?

Tags: html5-video, multipart, dcm4che, dicomweb

I am trying to setup a HTML page to point to a video. So basically I would need to know what is the source url I need to define inside my `<video/>` element ?

My server is simply a dcm4che server. I followed instructions from [here](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/wiki/Run-minimum-set-of-archive-services-on-a-single-host#use-docker-compose). Then I downloaded locally a sample DICOM/MP4 instance from [here](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/wiki/Run-minimum-set-of-archive-services-on-a-single-host#use-docker-compose). And then push that DICOM file to local dcm4che server:

```
$ curl -X POST --header 'Accept: application/dicom+json' \
 http://localhost:8080/dcm4chee-arc/aets/DCM4CHEE/rs/studies --header \
 'Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/dicom"' --form \ 
 "file1=@test_720.dcm;type=application/dicom"
```

However to retrieve the bulkdata, all I can find is the [multipart/related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#related) mechanism which does not seems to be supported by chrome:

```
% curl -o mp4.multipart -H "Accept: multipart/related; type=video/*" \
  http://localhost:8080/dcm4chee-arc/aets/DCM4CHEE/rs/studies/1.3.51.0.7.633920140505.6339234439.633987.633918098/series/1.3.51.5146.11682.20140505.122553197/instances/1.3.51.5146.1682.20140505.1225531.197
```

where:

```
% head -4 mp4.multipart
--6c391389-5d03-4e40-9fd1-c8be842e8c88
Content-Location: http://localhost:8080/dcm4chee-arc/aets/DCM4CHEE/rs/studies/1.3.51.0.7.633920140505.6339234439.633987.633918098/series/1.3.51.5146.11682.20140505.122553197/instances/1.3.51.5146.1682.20140505.1225531.197
Content-ID: <5caeda59-9477-40ec-a2e2-b69610923757@resteasy-multipart>
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

...and then eventually I see the binary `ftypisom` (so this is a valid MP4 file wrapped into a multipart/related header).

So if I understand correctly [chrome does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806228/browser-support-of-multipart-responses) multipart/related (I'd like to avoid using a javascript parser just to removing the first 5 lines of ASCII text), so my only possible solution would be to retrieve the MP4 using a different mechanism. But I did not find it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use WADO-URI instead of WADO-RS. For example:

```
% curl -o movie.mp4 \
 "http://localhost:8080/dcm4chee-arc/aets/DCM4CHEE/wado?requestType=WADO&studyUID=1.3.51.0.7.633920140505.6339234439.633987.633918098&seriesUID=1.3.51.5146.11682.20140505.122553197&objectUID=1.3.51.5146.1682.20140505.1225531.197&contentType=video/*"
```

---

An extension was added to the DICOM standard precisely for this use case. See:

- [CP 2204  Parts 18    Restore multipart bulkdata and clarify range requests](https://www.dclunie.com/dicom-status/status.html#CP2204)